# Implement country and language redirects (US, CA, En and Fr) in IIS

Tags: url, iis7

We have a website that has two URLs (one for the US side and another for the Canadian side which is then broken into Canadian English and Canadian French). For the purposes of my question,  I will write as:

- www.us_url.com (US)
- www.canada_url.ca/ca_en/ (Canadian English)
- www.canada_url.ca/ca_fr/ (Canadian French)

To make sure people are on the correct site, what do I do if they go to the US URL with Canadian English content (e.g. www.us_url.com/ca_en/canada.asp) but I want to make sure the URL is the Canadian one (e.g. www.canada_url.ca/ca_en/canada.asp) so it shows up properly in Google Analytics.

We're using IIS 7 and classic ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the URL rewrite module, you should be able to do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Check US" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="www.us_url.com" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="/ca_en*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.canada_url.ca/ca_en/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Check US 2" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="www.us_url.com" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="/ca_fr*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.canada_url.ca/ca_fr/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```